# images from array not showing

Tags: html, arrays, ajax, image

In my website I use a javascript function to get images from a datasource. It is working when the content 
is hard coded as shown below: (the real path is replaced by xxxx for obvious reasons)

```
function showcampopicture(data){
    var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({   
    wrapperid: "images", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow   
    dimensions: [450, 300], //
    imagearray:   [["https://xxxx/slikithumb/sliki/Schewnfeld.jpg"],
       ["https://xxxx/sliki/slikithumb/1/85_2018-11-13.jpg"], 
       ["https://xxxx/sliki/slikithumb/1/85_2018-11-12.jpg"], 
       ["https://xxxx/sliki/slikithumb/1/85_2018-10-28.jpg"]]
    displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:1000, cycles:0, wraparound:false},   
      persist: false, //
      fadeduration: 2000, //transition duration (milliseconds)  
      descreveal: "ondemand",
      togglerid: ""
      })    
    }
```

When I make a ajax request, I get the same content from:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "pictures_sql.php",

success: function(data){
     showcampopicture(data);
}
});
```

The problem is that my Cromebrowser cannot read the file paths and shows Content error:

```
[:1 GET https://xxxx/[ 404 (Not Found)
Image (async)
fadeSlideShow @ slide-show.js:1
showcampopicture @ campo_details.php:165
success @ campo_details.php:185
o @ 10b7194f44f2a10d55b4d05c5f6aacc2.js:3

h:1 GET https://xxxx/h 404 (Not Found)
```

Does anybody have a idea why the strange behaviour occurs? Thanks

More info:
I have tried this: calling the function  showcampopicture("https://xxxx.mypic.jpg") 
Gives the same result that the browser tries to chunk the string by every letter:
errror in Chrome: 
GET https://xxxx/s 404 (Not Found), 
GET https://xxxx/l 404 (Not Found)

--
So I have found the problem but not solved it. You need to pass an array. Quite simple but I just forgot that you have to convert the php data to a js array. I used json and it is working now.

Comment: It's not clear really clear what you're asking... you works when it's hardcoded, and have shown us that code, but you haven't shown us the code that doesn't work. I'm guessing that you are trying to pass in the images in the $data parameter, but you haven't actually made that clear. If so, please show us your code for getting the images from the $data parameter. It would also help if you told us of the results of any debugging you did.

Comment: @Peter, can you please tell me if the imagearray consists of url or file path, if it is a file path, you need to remove https:// part from the imagearray from all the images, Then it will directly point to your URL and treat the URL as a relative path. Otherwise, you need to add the full URL of the images.

Comment: Your hard coded `imagearray` is an array of arrays. What `data` gets returned from server ?  array or an array of arrays. If just an array, try inside the function `imagearray: [data]`.